# MacBook Air doesn't power on when the battery is connected

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, macbook-air

A friend asked me to look into his MacBook Air because it didn't want to power on anymore. Took a look at it, opened it, took the battery out and connected the charger cable and it worked every single time without issues.

When I connect the battery, it powers up only when it wants (random moments without a specific pattern). I tried with his old battery and a newly bought one as well and the same issue occurs. All connections seems to be in order and didn't see anything that can cause a short circuit from the battery.

If anyone else went through similar issues, can you advise on where to look or what the issue might be?

Comment: maybe a bad power supply

Answer (score 1):

Likely causes are:

- A weak battery - both replacement and original. Some batteries are [available for ~US$32](https://www.amazon.com/Battery-Replacement-Mac/s?k=Battery%20Replacement%20for%20Mac), but check the [battery status](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/check-the-condition-of-your-computers-battery-mh20865/mac), or better, check it **under load** to see if it's good.
- Intermittent connection in the battery branch of the power circuit. Look for loose connectors, a break *inside* a wire that was pinched by the case or bent, a break in the solder joint between connector and printed circuit board (PCB), or a broken trace on the PCB.
- A bad [voltage-equalizer](https://www.macbookproslow.com/fix-battery-issues/) in the PC for the battery (i.e., the part that connects to *each cell* of the battery to make sure it's not over- or under-charged.

If repairs are expensive, a workaround to make it portable again would be to use a small 12 V battery with a small inverter, such [as this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07DW1PSRH). Yes, it would be somewhat clunky, but at least affordable, and potentially able to last far longer than the Mac internal battery.

See this [site for more ideas](https://www.macbookproslow.com/fix-battery-issues/).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. As just a small update: a behavior I saw recently is: when only on battery, it does not power on, but the moment I connect the power adapter it turns on without touching the power on button. Does it help narrowing it down?

Comment: @AndyGix, Not  much... you've established it's a battery-power issue, but you knew that already.